# Missing argument for parameter #1 in call to Swift function

Tags: ios, swift

Very new to Swift and coding in general.
Just need some help getting my random selector to work. I am trying to make it choose a random number between 1 and 9 and check if that number is the same as the button you click.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oooVU.png)

Comment: Don't post screen shots. Post your actual code! Your code doesn't make any sense. Your buttonPressed returns void and for comparison you are supposed to use `==` instead of `=` and you are not supposed to call your IBAction programatically

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to compare the random number to the title (displayed number) on the clicked button?

If so, add this line above your if statement:

```
guard let buttonInt = sender.titleLabel?.text.flatMap(Int.init) else { return }
```

Then, change your if statement to look like so:

```
if randomNumber == buttonInt {

    // do what you want if it matches

} else {

    // handle no match
}
```

// EDIT: Props to Alexander for the flatMap version

Comment: You can do `guard let buttonInt = sender.titleLabel?.text.map(Int.init)` :)

Comment: @Alexander, just edited to reflect your suggestion, much cleaner, thanks! :)

Comment: Well you still need the `else { do something }`

Comment: now im getting this error, Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UInt32' and 'Int?'

Comment: Whoops, that was supposed to be `flatMap`, not `map`

Comment: Wrap `randomNumber` like so: `let rand = Int(randomNumber)` and then compare `rand` to `buttonInt`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check :

```
let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(9))
guard let buttonInt = Int(sender.currentTitle!) else { return }
if rand == buttonInt {

} else {

}
```